# Empty ResultSet after executing PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I execute sql query `SELECT * FROM TABLE (TEST.getDevices())` in SqlDeveloper I've got about 200 rows, but when I try to execute it in java:

```
//cut here
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE (TEST.getDevices())"; 
PreparedStatement stmt = null; 
ResultSet rset = null; 
try { 
    stmt = oracleConnection.prepareStatement(query); 
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(); 
    rset.next(); 
    System.out.println(rset.getInt(1));
//cut here
```

I get empty ResultSet and so on the exception is thrown.
I've tried query `SELECT Count(*) a FROM TABLE (TEST.getDevices())`
In SqlDeveloper result is 200, in java app is 0.

What could be reason that get empty ResultSet in ma app?

Comment: Permissions/rights of the application vs. the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the DB connection.

Comment: Yes, but was ok. 
Problem resolved - it was error in database, app was quering in context of user who didn't have rights to read that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that TEST.getDevices() return TYPE "TABLE OF" or getDevices is PIPELINED FUNCTION? If true, you can try this trick:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_DEVICES AS SELECT * FROM TABLE(TEST.getDevices());
```

Than it shoud work from Java and SQLDeveloper:

```
DESC VIEW_DEVICES;
```

or select statement

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_DEVICES;
```

You can replace you query to:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM VIEW_DEVICES";
```

Or you can try search in google something like "how to map varray in java from oracle".