# Empty ResultSet for non-empty database table after PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have written a query which retrieves data from a table and then I am checking the number of rows in the resultset using `getRow()` method. This is printing `0`,however my table contains multiple row column data in it.

I checked previous questions here and found one much similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573166/empty-resultset-after-executing-preparedstatement). But unlike what is mentioned in that I do not have any permissions defined and connection to the database is well established. It is a very simple query returning updatable resultset as following:

```
if(temp == null) {
                query = "SELECT * FROM altemp1";
                pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                temp = pstmt.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("TEMP LENGTH : "+temp.getRow());
            }
```

**temp** is the **ResultSet** and **altemp1** is the **table** in DB.
The check above if `temp` is null? is for some logical purpose.

Comment: The `getRow` method doesn't return the number of rows in the resultset; it returns the current row number. In the example code, the query (prepared statement) is executed, but no rows are fetched from the resultset, so the current row number from the resultset is 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ResultSet.next()` and check the return code to fetch each successive row, including the first, and you then need to call various other methods to get the columns, one of which is *not* `getRow()`. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29):

> [...getRow()] retrieves the current row number. The first row is number 1, the second number 2, and so on.